# Car exhaust spraying water (Honda Fit)

Tags: honda, exhaust, head-gasket

I have a question which isn't quite answered in any of the previous posts I looked through on water and exhausts.

I went to look at a 2011 Honda Jazz/Fit today as a possible used car purchase. I was generally happy with the car except for the amount of water coming out the exhaust. I understand some drips of condensation is normal, but this was more like a shower of water being sprayed out of the exhaust, rather than just a drip.

Even after idling for several minutes, water was blowing out the exhaust under pressure like a small rain shower. I could hold my hand 10-15 cm away from the exhaust and it would feel like I was being rained on.

Does this sound like normal levels of
condensation, or is there likely to be something more seriously wrong?

There was no smoke accompanying the water. It was also a hot day.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Is this before taking it for a drive or after?

Comment: What you describe is not normal but I'm at a loss to explain it.  The only thing that makes sense is that there is a serious head gasket leak and it's allowing coolant to flow into the cylinder and be blown out the exhaust.

Comment: This was just idling without a test drive. Unfortunately I didn't get to take it out for a drive but would do before buying if it came to that. A head gasket leak is one issue I was worried about. In any case if it is indeed abnormal then I will probably stay away from the car. Wouldn't want to buy something knowing it has a mystery issue.

Comment: Before you pass on this, if you otherwise like it,  you may want to take it for a test drive and let it warm up.  After that there should be little to no liquid water exiting the tailpipe except if it's very cold out.  There are lots of "nooks and crannies" in a modern exhaust system that can hold water and until things get up to operating temperature all the way to the tailpipe, some water can spew out.  I was using  your description in judging if this was normal but that can be quite subjective.

Comment: Considering that roughly 40 % the molecules in the exhaust are water , it is no surprise that the exhaust system must be well warmed to keep all the water as a gas/vapor/steam. For example a fuel molecule like octane has 8 carbons and 10 hydrogens . When burned that is 8 carbon dioxide and 5 water molecules in the exhaust.  So there is substantial amount of water in the exhaust and if condensed in a cool system it is noticeable.

Comment: If the car has been started often and not been for a good drive, the exhaust boxes could have lots of water in them as @blacksmith37 suggests.  Take it for a good drive and then check it.  Also check the coolant level after the drive.

Comment: How did the exhaust smell? Or at least the liquid which had deposited itself on your hand?

Comment: Couldn't detect a smell at all so I'm assuming it's just water. Sounds like the general consensus is that if I take it for a drive and see no water coming out the exhaust after it should be fine. Thanks all